# Importing excel data through a stored proc

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, import, identity-column

How to import data from Excel sheet into a table that has identity seed column? I have a stored proc to INSERT, how do I call it while creating an SSIS package where I mapped the excel columns to the database columns in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a sproc to do this within SSIS.  If you have mapped the Excel Source to the destination, the data flow will do the insert.  You may need a data conversion task, since the strings in the Excel data will be unicode and SQL prefers DT_STR.